# Distance between the header and the title in ConTeXt's enumerations

Tags: formatting, theorems, context-mkiv

I have defined in ConTeXt an enumeration for definitions:

```
\defineenumeration[definition][theorem][
    text={Definition},
    prefix=chapter,
    way=bychapter,
    right=.,
    titleleft=(,
    titleright=.),
    distance=0.5em,
    headstyle=\ss,
    title=yes,
    titlestyle=\ss,
    alternative=serried,
    width=broad,
    indentnext=no]
```

I would like to set the distance between the header, i.e. "Defintion [numberOfTheDefintion]", and the title thereof to 0.5em (just like I set with the `distance` key the distance between the title and the text of the definition).

Thank you.

Comment: Use `titledistance=0.5em`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aditya said, the solution is to set the `titledistance` key to `0.5em` like this:

```
\defineenumeration[definition][theorem][
    text={Definition},
    prefix=chapter,
    way=bychapter,
    right=.,
    title=yes,
    titledistance=0.5em, % the "titledistance" key does the job
    titleleft=(,
    titleright=.),
    distance=0.5em,
    headstyle=\ss,
    titlestyle=\ss,
    alternative=serried,
    width=broad,
    indentnext=no]
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is rather a comment, but not an answer

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: I am curious. Why do you not consider this a complete answer?

Comment: @Aditya: At the time I wrote my comment, there was no source added, just one line of text ;-)